# Grid conditional for a file(s) - If file exists display content (file)

Tags: conditionals, grid, files

I have a grid field (files), with a column/variable (file). I just need to display my content/snippet if a file has been uploaded.

So something like:

```
{if files:file}link to my file{/if}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do it exactly like you think.

{my_grid_field}
    {if my_grid_field:column}{my_grid_field:column}{/if}
{/my_grid_field}

Comment: Thank you for this! I was trying to get it to work by displaying a snippet, but for some reason that does work: {if files:file}{my_snippet}{/if}. Is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out by doing this

```
{if files}{my_snippet}{/if}
```

And then in my snippet

```
{files}
<a href="{files:file}">{files:file_name}</a>
{/files}
```